# Creating Array with Comparison from Other Arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I have a simple problem, but I'm hitting some hurdles. The problem is like this, I have 2 arrays:

```
a=['A','B','C','D','E']
i=['C','F']
```

I'm trying to compare the two and where an item in the 2nd array(i) does not match an item in the first, I'm trying to update the array(i) with the position of the mismatch, and fill it with a blank value ('')

So, I'm trying to end up with this solution:

```
i=['','',C,'','',F]
```

I tried the insert method:

```
for n,x in enumerate(a):
    for item in i:
       if x != item:
          i.insert(n,'')
```

not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This list comprehension will do what you're after:

```
a_set = set(a) # using sets allows the `in` function to run in
i_set = set(i) # constant time vs. running in linear time (its faster for large data sets)
[x if x in i_set else "" for x in a] + [x for x in i if x not in a_set]
```

It goes through each item of `a` first. If it appears in `i`, it adds the item, otherwise it adds `""`. Then it goes through each item of `i`, checks if it appears in `a`, and if not, adds it to the list. These two lists are then appended to each other using the `+` operator.

You can then assign this to `i` to get the output you're after.

```
>>> a_set = set(a)
>>> i_set = set(i)
>>> i =[x if x in i_set else "" for x in a] + [x for x in i if x not in a_set]
>>> i
["", "", "C", "", "", "F"]
```

Comment: Using a set for `... if x in i ...` and for `... if x not in a]` should make this code run significantly more quickly for large data sets

Comment: I am not sure if order preservation matters, but it should be noted that if `i=['0', 'C', 'F']` this gives the result of `['', '', 'C', '', '', '0', 'F']` rather than `['0', '', '', 'C', '', '', 'F']`.

Comment: @JulesTamagnan Thanks.

Comment: Thanks OrangeFlash and everyone